# Adding multiple dynamic lines to highcharts

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have 2 sets of data being returned from an API which i need to chart to a line graph, the problem is i dont know which set of results will come at any given time, so i need something that will be able to chart both sets of the results.

The first set has the following info, ( taken from a var_dump )

```
'series' => string '[{name: 'Data'}]'
'data_lines' => string '[[[1473731108000,3.4804],[1473731406000,1.7047],[1473731704000,1.7559],[1473732004000,1.2774],[1473732304000,1.9295]]]'
```

The first number is a timestamp, and the second number is the plot point in GB, and the series name is the series name obviously.

The above set of results only needs one line, the second set of data is an averaging set of results and needs 3 lines, its response is as follows:

```
'series' => string '[{name: 'Data (average)'},{name: 'Data (maximum)'},{name: 'Data (minimum)'}]'
'data_lines' => string '[[[1473638400000,1.5094]],[[1473638400000,6.7825]],[[1473638400000,1.0546]]]'
```

and this one obviously has 3 data values for the 3 labels per timestamp.

Any help in getting this going would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an image/sketch of how it's supposed to look?

Comment: Well i guess the first set of data would be a single line graph and the second set would be a 3 line graph like here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Comment: Do you have a live example showing what have you done till this moment? Have you seen Highcharts custom preprocessing examples in their docs? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

Comment: So what part of this are you having trouble with? I'm not seeing an actual question here, and not enough detail on what you actually want, and what isn't working, to offer any help.

Comment: Agreeing with the others, that there is not enough information. It sounds like you need to check the data when it's returned and branch the code according to the type of data returned (or if not branch at least change some parameters to produce the type of result you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

This is my sugestion: Create a function that will act like a router for your results. I don't know how you are processing your results (PHP or javascript), BTW:

```
function chartSelector($data) {
    if (count($data['series']) == 3) {
        //put the logic to process the averaging set of results here
    } else {
        //put the logic for the other set here
    }
}
```

This function will direct the processing according to the given set of data :)